# How to revert event to its original state after clicking on it again?

Tags: javascript, css, frontend

I'm relatively new to web-development and I am building a portfolio website. I have these triangle bullet points I made using borders. Originally, they are pointing to the right and the idea is to be able to click on them and then have them point down (like an arrow) to then show some image (haven't gotten to that part yet) and then point back to the right when clicked again. I can get them to point down, but I tried implementing both point down and point left functions and now nothing happens when I click on it. I tried using an if statement but that didn't work either. I did a lot of research but nothing really covered my exact problem, maybe I'm not googling the right terms.

```
const projectList = document.getElementById('projects').querySelector('ul');
const projectPsuedo = projectList.querySelectorAll('span');

const switchBulletDown = event => {
    event.target.style.borderLeftColor = 'transparent';
    event.target.style.borderTopColor = '#111';
    event.target.style.left = '-1.2em';
    event.target.style.top = '1.6em';
}

const switchBulletRight = event => {
    event.target.style.borderLeftColor = '#111';
    event.target.style.borderTopColor = 'transparent';
    event.target.style.left = '-1em';
    event.target.style.top = '1.4em';
}

const eventHandler = psuedoClass => {
    if (psuedoClass.style.borderLeftColor === '#111') {
        psuedoClass.addEventListener('click', switchBulletDown);
    } else {
        psuedoClass.addEventListener('click', switchBulletRight);
    }    
}

projectPsuedo.forEach(eventHandler);
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Also please look into delegation. You almost never need to add an event handler to sibling elements

Comment: Another recomendation is to use classes instead of inline styles. it's more reliable to have something like `if (element.classList.contains('onstate')) {...}` than it is to do `if (element.style.borderLeftColor==='#111')`. Plus, with classes you get your desired outcome with something as simple as `element.addEventListener('click', e=> { e.target.closest('.container').classList.toggle('open') })` - your CSS will know that when the container class has 'open' in it, the caret will point down, the content will show, etc.

Comment: This can be easily done without JavaScript and only CSS using the `rotate()` property.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it to work and I used the .toggle method to switch between classes.

```
const projectList = document.getElementById('projects').querySelector('ul');
const projectPsuedo = projectList.querySelectorAll('span');

const eventHandler = psuedoClass => {
    psuedoClass.addEventListener('click', () => {
        psuedoClass.classList.toggle('point-down')
    })
}

projectPsuedo.forEach(eventHandler);
```